# In Python, how can I map values onto other another scale?

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to programming and math, so forgive me if I'm not asking this question in the right way. Basically I have a range of dates, like this:

```
dateList = ['1818', '1813', '1818', '1811', '1813']
```

and I want to plot these eventually, but the plot function needs values between, say, 30 and 80 in order to look good. That means the min of this set, 1811, should be at 30, and the max, 1818, should be at 80. Is there a way to write a function fancyMap such that:

```
fancyMap(dateList, (30, 80))
```

outputs something like (guessing here):

```
[80, 52, 80, 30, 52]
```

I know there's some simple math involved here, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: I think the lowest value in your input will map to the min bound you pass to the map function, right?  In your example, 1811 should be transformed to 20 in the output set.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding exactly what you're asking here.

Comment: Yep. That 20 was supposed to be 30. Thanks for noticing that. Corrected.

Comment: The concept is called "linear interpolation" but I want to check; are your low-high arguments (30, 80) always positive?

Comment: Oh cool. Yep, they're always positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an addition to Claris' answer, this function works for different bounds:

```
def fancyMap(array, low, high):
    array = [int(numeric_string) for numeric_string in array]
    minimum = min(array)
    maximum = max(array)

    diff = maximum - minimum
    diffScale = high - low

    return map ( lambda x: int((int(x)-minimum)*(float(diffScale)/diff)+low), array)
```

Comment: Your use of `int` doesn't work, it is scaling to 79, not 80

Comment: Now this should work fine. It was doing an integer division with `diffScale/diff`

Comment: You could also do `from __future__ import division` to avoid the integer division.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
dateList = ['1818', '1813', '1818', '1811', '1813']
print map ( lambda x: (int(x)-1811)*(50.0/7)+30, dateList )
```

or

```
print map ( lambda x: int((int(x)-1811)*(50.0/7)+30), dateList )
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you dynamically pull out the min and max and compute the scaling factor and offset rather than hard coding them.